# Using macros in Memoir chapter for a Diary

Tags: memoir, datetime, currfile

I'm trying to create an automatic chapter head which displays the day of the week and date (kind of like a diary entry) I have a directory called "august" within which is a file called 01.tex. The parent file 08.tex (08 for August) calls for 01.tex.  see my WME

main file 08.tex:

```
\documentclass{memoir}    
\usepackage[parent]{currfile}    
\let\ordinal\relax    
\usepackage[dayofweek]{datetime}    
\newcommand{\diarydate}{\formatdate{\currfilebase}{\parentfilebase}{2014}}


\begin{document}

\input{08/1.tex}

\end{document}
```

08/1.tex:

```
\chapter{\diarydate}
```

The errors I get:

> ./08/1.tex:1: Use of \@chapter doesn't match its definition. [\chapter{\lauddate}]
>   ./08/1.tex:1: Argument of \@gobbletwo has an extra }. [\chapter{\lauddate}]
>   ./08/1.tex:1: Paragraph ended before \@gobbletwo was complete. [\chapter{\lauddate}]

Comment: Use `\DeclareRobustCommand` instead `\newcommad`.

Comment: In my point of view this question needs more explanation

Comment: Thank you wipet, that works. Sorry for my ignorance but is this okay to do... is it a good practice or am I using duct tape on sloppy way of doing things (if you see what I mean)

Comment: @theobear This is a practice in LaTeX: usage of `\DeclareRobustCommand` for macros which are used in titles of chapters, sections. For normal macros, the `\newcommand` is sufficient. LaTeX isn't my business; you can read more about this in LaTeX manuals.

Comment: @wipet Want to write up an answer?

Comment: Related: [Using currfile and Datetime to format a diary page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220574)