# Using currfile and Datetime to format a diary page

Tags: datetime, currfile

To create something like a diary, I am using a number of input files within 2 directories a MONTH directory named 01-12 and a day directory within each month...01-31

so

12/ (December) which has a file 12.tex which inputs 12/01/01.tex (there is also a 12/02/02.tex and so on...the day tex file calls a bunch of other files from the day directory)

The idea was to have `currfile` print out the the month directory name and the day directory name and so use that to create headers and chapter heads automatically. I would just need to put in the year and it wouldput the right day of the week and date on the correct page.

I started exploring this here: [Using macros in Memoir chapter for a Diary](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/195220/26651) but changed my method a bit and using this answer to my last question:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/220450/26651

I thought I had my solution...

I tried this:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\dateforheader}{\formatdate{\StrBehind{\currfiledir}{/}[\currfilesubdir]\StrBefore{\currlastdir}{/}}{\StrBefore{\parentfiledir}{/}}{2015}}
```

and I tried this

```
 \DeclareRobustCommand{\MyDay}{{\StrBehind{\currfiledir}{/}[\currfilesubdir]\StrBefore{\currlastdir}{/}}
 \DeclareRobustCommand{\MyMonth}{\StrBefore{\parentfiledir}{/}}

\formatdate{\MyDay}{\MyMonth}{2015}
```

hoping to use them in a page header

```
\makeoddhead{mypagestyle}{}{\dateforheader}{\thepage}
```

This doesn't work.

nor does it work to just use the macro on the 12/01/01.tex page:

```
\dateforheader
```

though

```
\MyDay 
\MyMonth
```

will work by themselves

my error messages:

```
./12/1/1.tex:4: Missing number, treated as zero. [{\dateforheader]
./12/1/1.tex:4: Undefined control sequence. [{\dateforheader]
./12/1/1.tex:4: Missing number, treated as zero. [{\dateforheader]
./12/1/1.tex:4: Missing number, treated as zero. [{\dateforheader]
./12/1/1.tex:4: Undefined control sequence. [{\dateforheader]
./12/1/1.tex:4: Missing number, treated as zero. [{\dateforheader]
./12/1/1.tex:4: Package datetime Error: Invalid Month number 0. [{\dateforheader]
```

---

UPDATE:

using @karlkoeller answer below I created a MWE but it doesn't seem to work for me so I thought I would test the individual macros using the MWE below:

Set up home directory inside is test.tex with this code:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{currfile}
\usepackage{import}

\StrBehind{\currfiledir}{/}[\currfilesubdir]
\StrBefore{\currfilesubdir}{/}[\MyDay]
\StrBefore{\currfiledir}{/}[\MyMonth]

\newcommand{\mydate}{\MyDay, \MyMonth}

\begin{document}
\input{8/8.tex}
\end{document}
```

within the home directory there is a directory called 8 within that

a tex file called 8.tex with the following code:

```
 \input{8/1/1.tex}
```

also witin directory 8 is directory 1 with the 1.tex file with the code below... which I thought would test the marcros:

```
currfiledir:\currfiledir

part 1 of My Day: \StrBehind{\currfiledir}{/}

part 2 of My Day: \StrBefore{\currfilesubdir}{/}

MyMonth: \StrBefore{\currfiledir}{/}

date: \mydate
```

---

the results are below:

currfiledir: 8/1/

part 1 of My Day: 1/

part 2 of My Day:

MyMonth: 8

date: ,

---

any ideas what is wrong here?

Comment: You say `\MyDay` doesn't work. And then you say it does. It would be helpful if you posted a complete MWE with everything in one place.

Comment: Sorry, that was an error... it's edited. Will poste a MWE if the answer below doesn't help... though because of the multiple pieces I may have to post a zip file with directories... which is why I hesitated.

Comment: I've updated my question with a MWE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to save the results of string manipulations in macros, so that they can be used as arguments for `\formatdate`.

So, replace your code with

```
\StrBehind{\currfiledir}{/}[\currfilesubdir]
\StrBefore{\currfilesubdir}{/}[\MyDay]
\StrBefore{\currfiledir}{/}[\MyMonth]
```

The above lines have to be put at the beginning of each one of your `<day>.tex` files.

At this point `\MyDay` contains the day's number and `\MyMonth` the month's number and you can define

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\dateforheader}{\formatdate{\MyDay}{\MyMonth}{2015}}
```

which has to be put in your main file.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{datetime}

%\usepackage{currfile}            % uncomment this line in your mainfile.tex
\newcommand{\currfiledir}{12/01/} % comment this line in your mainfile.tex

\usepackage{lipsum} % Just for the example

\StrBehind{\currfiledir}{/}[\currfilesubdir] % to be put in each <day>.tex
\StrBefore{\currfilesubdir}{/}[\MyDay]       % to be put in each <day>.tex
\StrBefore{\currfiledir}{/}[\MyMonth]        % to be put in each <day>.tex

\DeclareRobustCommand{\dateforheader}{\formatdate{\MyDay}{\MyMonth}{2015}} % to be put in your mainfile.tex

\makeoddhead{headings}{}{\dateforheader}{\thepage} % to be put in your mainfile.tex (change headings to mypagestyle)

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried it and ran into problems so I created a MWE. I've updated my question with the results.

Comment: @theobar I've added some comments in the code to distinguish where various part have to be put. Hope it is clear now.